# Why my asp.net drop down list text align not set to center?

Tags: html, asp.net

I use drop down in my web application ,but when i run that i see text alignment not set to center,my drop down list html code is this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="width:50%;text-align:center;" forecolor="White" BackColor="#2E3842">
<asp:ListItem>یزد</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>aaa</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>bbb</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

how can i set text to center?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centre align drop down list text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665137/centre-align-drop-down-list-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net dropdownlist align text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761022/net-dropdownlist-align-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aligning text center in a `dropdown` (select list) is not possible with css `text-align`. You can in fact use `text-indent` or `padding`

like

```
select{text-indent:5px}
```

```html
<select style="padding-left: 5px;">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<select style="text-indent: 25px;width: 80px;">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
 <style>
            select
            {
                width: 50%;
                 text-indent: 50%;
                color: White;
                background-color: #2E3842;
            }
        </style>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
            <asp:ListItem>یزد</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>aaa</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>bbb</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this if margin is not an issue for select tag:

```
margin-left:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional.

for align left or right

direction:ltr;       //rtl

Answer (score 0):

The solution is margin:0px auto;